# How to find the parametric vector $r(u,v)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

find the  area of that portion of the paraboloid $x^2 + z^2 = 2ay$ which is cut off by the
plane $y = a$

**My Question** : How to find the parametric vector  $r(u,v)$  of the given paraboloid cut off by the plane $y = a$?

**My attempt** :I was thinking about $x = r \cos θ$, $y = r \sin θ$ but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the circle $x^2+z^2=2a^2$ in the plane $y=a$

$\left(a\sqrt{2} \cos t,a,a\sqrt{2} \sin t\right);\;t\in [0,2\pi]$

It's area is $2a^2\pi$

[image]

Comment: thanks  a  lots for diagram @Raffaele sir