# Evaluate the I?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

This  is question is inspired from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3996511/how-to-find-the-parametric-vector-ru-v)

find the value   of $$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\sqrt 2 a}\sqrt{ \frac{u^4}{a^2} +u^2} du dv$$

My attempt : $$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\sqrt 2 a}u\sqrt{ \frac{u^2}{a^2} +1} du dv$$

after that im not able to solved this

Comment: $I=a^2\pi \int_0^{\sqrt2 a} (2u/a^2) (u^2/a^2+1)^{1/2}du$

Comment: substitute $t = \frac{u^2}{a^2} + 1$

Comment: An observation to begin with: $$
I = \left( {\int_0^{2\pi } {dv} } \right)\left( {\int_0^{\sqrt 2 a} {\sqrt {\frac{{u^4 }}{{a^2 }} + u^2 } du} } \right).
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I worked out a complete solution, @TitoEliatron has left a key step in his comment.

\begin{align}
I&=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\sqrt 2 a}u\sqrt{ \frac{u^2}{a^2} +1} \,du \, dv\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}dv \; \frac12 \int_0^{\sqrt2 a} \sqrt{ \frac{u^2}{a^2} +1} \, d(u^2) \\
&= \pi \int_0^{2a^2} \sqrt{x/a^2 + 1} \, dx \tag{$x = u^2$} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{a} \int_0^{2a^2} \sqrt{x + a^2} \, dx \\
&= \frac{2\pi}{3a} \left[ (x+a^2)^{3/2} \right]_0^{2a^2} \\
&= \frac{2\pi (3\sqrt3 - 1) a^2}{3}
\end{align}

Edit : The $a^3$ in the numerator cancelled with $a$ in the denominator to give $a^2$.

Answer (score 2):

For

$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt 2 a}u\sqrt{ \frac{u^2}{a^2} +1} du $$

use the substitution $t= \frac{u^2}{a^2}+1$. Then you get the integral

$$\frac{a^2}{2}\int_1^3 \sqrt{t} dt,$$

which is independent of $v$, hence

$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt 2 a}u\sqrt{ \frac{u^2}{a^2} +1} du = 2 \pi \cdot \frac{a^2}{2}\int_1^3 \sqrt{t} dt.$$

Comment: When $u = \sqrt2 a$, $t = \frac{2a^2}{a^2} + 1 = 3$.

Comment: Ooops, you are right.